# HTML & CSS: Fixed position when no scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, css-position

I'm making a template for a website with a "fixed footer block (FF_BLOCK)", some content and a "background image block (BG_BLOCK)" (also with some content).

When there is not much content, BG_BLOCK should be placed directly above the FF_BLOCK (position: fixed; bottom: 0px). I never want a gap between the FF_BLOCK and the BG_BLOCK.

When there is much content (and a scrollbar), the BG_BLOCK can be shown as it is now.

Is this possible with HTML + CSS only, or is the use of JS inevitable?

Current HTML

```
<div id="navigation">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div id="BG_BLOCK">...</div>
<div id="FF_BLOCK">...</div>
```

Current CSS

```
#BG_BLOCK {
background: url(../images/background.jpg) repeat-x top center;
height: 380px;
padding-top: 467px;
margin-top: -347px;
}

#FF_BLOCK {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

See this image: [image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Good idea, I changed the question

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `min-height`:?

```
BG_BLOCK {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I'm assuming the background image is large enough. If not, use `background-size: cover` or `background-size: auto 100%` to fill the entire screen.

Comment: The background image is not an issue here, the top is #000, so it's only repeated horizontally. Can you post an example with the code above? I tried a min-height for the BG_BLOCK, without succes...

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try, I found an example with min-height, that could do the trick...

Comment: Oops. Sorry that I didn't reply to your first comment, was quite busy in the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared FF_BLOCK (position: fixed). with that your FF_BLOCK has been removed from the normal flow of page.
use the min-height with some positioning other then fixed.